# how to display specific div on button click using jquery bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have four buttons in a button group and I want a specific button has to show some specific div content on its click.

The content has to show according to which button is clicked.

How can I do this using twitter bootstrap jQuery in asp.net?

Comment: The best answer for you question is [**`this`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).  Look into the documentation and you can fix it by yourself.

Comment: Aren't you trying to do [tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav) ?

Comment: No i want it on button click only..

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a way to do with **`jQuery`**

```
$('.btn-group').find('button').click(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
    // here you can check the value and act upon
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/ZpLgc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap **[Collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)**. According to the documentation:

> Just add data-toggle="collapse" and a data-target to element to automatically assign control of a collapsible element. The data-target attribute accepts a CSS selector to apply the collapse to. Be sure to add the class collapse to the collapsible element. If you'd like it to default open, add the additional class in.

Here is a basic demo. http://www.bootply.com/jIyBm4IaoL .

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">
    btn1 
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2">
    btn2
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo3">
    btn3
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo4">
    btn4
</button>
<div id="demo1" class="collapse">
    ddassdfsdf
</div>
<div id="demo2" class="collapse">
    2343434  
</div>
<div id="demo3" class="collapse">
    465656 vbgtrsdf
</div>
<div id="demo4" class="collapse">
    4545bn c sasdasdfasd
</div>
```